# How to put multiple paragraphs in single \loop .... \repeat

Tags: paragraphs, plain-tex, loops

I wanted to create list of n Fibonaci numbers. This is my code so far:

```
\newcount\n
\n=5

\newcount\a
\newcount\b
\newcount\i
\a = 1 
\b = 1 
\i = 0 

$a = \the\a$ \par
$b = \the\b$ \par
$i = \the\i$ \par
\vskip 15mm
\hrule
\loop
$\the\b$
\advance\b by \a
\multiply\a by -1
\advance\a by \b  
\advance\i by 1
\ifnum\i<\n
\repeat
\bye
```

I'd like to have all numbers on a separate lines but TeX doesn't allow `\par` in `\loop ... \repeat` construction. Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks for any directions.

Comment: Just use `\endgraf`: `$\the\b$\endgraf`. `\par` wouldn't work because `\loop` is not a `\long` macro, but `\endgraf` does the same, with other name.

Answer (score 2):

`\endgraf` is a renamed `\par` for such use:

```
\newcount\n
\n=5

\newcount\a
\newcount\b
\newcount\i
\a = 1 
\b = 1 
\i = 0 

$a = \the\a$ \par
$b = \the\b$ \par
$i = \the\i$ \par
\vskip 15mm
\hrule
\loop
$\the\b$
\endgraf
\advance\b by \a
\multiply\a by -1
\advance\a by \b  
\advance\i by 1
\ifnum\i<\n
\repeat
\bye
```

Comment: or you could copy the definition of `\loop` from latex, which would allow a blank line or `\par`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you could also put the loop in a group with obeylines. This command turns lines of input into lines that are typeset as a line. It should be used inside a group to limit its scope.

```
\newcount\n
\n=5

\newcount\a
\newcount\b
\newcount\i
\a = 1 
\b = 1 
\i = 0 

$a = \the\a$ \par
$b = \the\b$ \par
$i = \the\i$ \par
\vskip 15mm
\hrule
{\obeylines
 \loop
   $\the\b$
   \advance\b by \a
   \multiply\a by -1
   \advance\a by \b  
   \advance\i by 1
 \ifnum\i<\n
 \repeat
\par}
\bye
```

The group allows to implement the loop in a more efficient way if you need higher
values for \n than 5. (The value of \n is restored at the end of the group.)

```
{\obeylines
  \i=\n
  \loop 
    \n=\b
    \advance\b by \a
    \hbox to40pt{\hss\the\b}
    \a=\n  
    \advance\i by -1
  \ifnum\i>0
  \repeat
\par}
```